# ChartJS - How can I skip certain minutes on the X-Axis

Tags: chart.js

I'm using **ChartJS** to visualize a database (that I have transformed into an array [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG6yU.png))

The problem is that I have various time differences between every point.
[Current visualization of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpGTQ.png).

My question is, how can I add space on my X axis, based on the time difference between the two data samples? Thanks.

EDIT: I was not very clear about what I wanted to achieve with my question, let me clarify:

I currently have this code:

```
  var worldctx = document.getElementById('worldChart').getContext('2d');
  var worldChart = new Chart(worldctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: worldArrayTime,
      datasets: [{ 
          data: worldArrayData,
          label: "WORLD",
          borderColor: "#3e95ce",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95ce",
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Taric Ranking'
      },
      scales:{
        xAxes:[{
          ticks:{
            callback: function(dataLabel,index){
              let a = Math.floor(worldArrayData.length/10)
              return index % a == 0 ? dataLabel : '';
            }
          }
        }],
        yAxes:[{
          ticks:{
            min: Math.floor(Math.min.apply(Math,worldArrayData)-2),
            max: Math.floor(Math.max.apply(Math,worldArrayData)+2)
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It gives me this Chart, but the X axis doesn't match the time spent between each point, how can I make it so that it represents accurately the time on the X axis?
[image: my chart]

Comment: Hi. Please add a screenshot of the "ideal" chart you want (Very hard to understand your issue for now). Also, next time paste her a code (google "markdown code") instead of jpeg with screenshot of code. Try this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Also you can use property `displayFormats` according to [Display Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) from Chart.js documentation. See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for the allowed format strings.

To do so, add the following to your `xAxis` inside the chart `options`.

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    displayFormats: {
      minute: 'DD/MM hh:mm'
    }
  }, 
  ...
```

> Please note that Chart.js uses Moment.js for the functionality of the
>   time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

```js
const worldArray = [{ time: 1583593111036, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583593163490, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583593233697, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583594921644, rank: 666 }, { time: 1583595055581, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583595404573, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583596247042, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583598655437, rank: 666 }, { time: 1583600457443, rank: 667 }, { time: 1583601460665, rank: 668 }, { time: 1583602660570, rank: 665 }, { time: 1583604281776, rank: 668 }, { time: 1583605854175, rank: 669 }, { time: 1583606447275, rank: 668 }, { time: 1583607161055, rank: 667 }, { time: 1583607882093, rank: 666 }, { time: 1583608179707, rank: 667 }, { time: 1583609744777, rank: 668 }, { time: 1583609860652, rank: 669 }, { time: 1583610648775, rank: 670 }, { time: 1583613344874, rank: 671 }, { time: 1583613459587, rank: 672 }];
const worldArrayTime = worldArray.map(o => o.time);
const worldArrayData = worldArray.map(o => o.rank);

var worldctx = document.getElementById('worldChart').getContext('2d');
var worldChart = new Chart(worldctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: worldArrayTime,
    datasets: [{
      data: worldArrayData,
      label: "WORLD",
      borderColor: "#3e95ce",
      backgroundColor: "#3e95ce",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Taric Ranking'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          tooltipFormat: 'DD/MM hh:mm',
          displayFormats: {
            minute: 'DD/MM hh:mm'
          }
        },         
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: worldArrayData.length
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: Math.floor(Math.min.apply(Math, worldArrayData) - 2),
          max: Math.floor(Math.max.apply(Math, worldArrayData) + 2)
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="worldChart" height="150"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Chartist.js since it offers an easier implementation of moment.js

If you know how to answer the question, i'm still interested tho.